Proof of Union bound identity in Probability.
I'm attempting the below problem from MIT discrete math problem set and I want to know if my proof is correct. I did not used induction as hinted in the question.
Question: Prove the following probabilistic identity, referred to as the Union Bound.
You may assume the theorem that the probability of a union of disjoint sets is the sum of
their probabilities.
Theorem: Let A1, . . . , An be a collection of events on some sample space. Then:
$
Pr(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Pr(A_i)
$
(Hint: Induction)
My Proof:
If the sets are disjoint , then by sum rule:
$
Pr(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Pr(A_i)
$
If sets are not dijoint, then:
$
Pr(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) < \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Pr(A_i)
$
Since the probabilities of overlapping outcomes are counted twice. Hence:
$
Pr(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Pr(A_i)
$
Is my proof correct?

$\text{Pr}(A_1\cup A_2)<P(A_1)+P(A_2)$ is in general wrong. The intersection of $A_i\cap A_j$ can always be a null set.

Show true for $n=2$ and use induction. Note that $A_1 \cup A_2 = A_1 \setminus A_2 \cup (A_1 \cap A_2) \cup A_2 \setminus A_1$ and note that the last 3 sets are disjoint.

Or just take the expectation of ${\bf1}{\cup{i=1}^nA_i} \le \sum_{i=1}^n{\bf1}_{A_i}.\ $

@Konstruktor if the intersection is null, then it comes under the first case I have mentioned. In other words they are disjoint, they have absolutely no elements in common. $Pr(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) < \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Pr(A_i)$ only if they are not disjoint, they have elements in common.

@AzharKhan a Nullset is in general not empty. Consider for example a normal distribution, then $\text{Pr}_{\text{Normal}}(\mathbb Z)=0$ applies.

@Konstruktor I just started with probability from their 6.042 course (available on YouTube), so far distribution or anything related to it is not covered so far, so I cannot understand your statement right now. But what I'm getting so far from you right now is my proof is wrong because $Pr(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) < \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Pr(A_i)$ does not always hold. It seems kinda bizarre to me right now since I'm making this argument considering the sets are not disjoint, i.e they have elements in common.

@AzharKhan In general, $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$, so $P(A\cup B)<P(A)+P(B)$ iff $P(A\cap B)>0$. The point is that $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$ does not imply $P(A\cap B)>0,$ so it is a mistake to claim that $A\cap B\ne
\emptyset$ implies $P(A\cup B)<P(A)+P(B).$ In many cases -- e.g. Konstructor's example of $A=\Bbb Z$ (the set of all integers) and $B=\Bbb R$ (the set of all real numbers) -- there will be events with the property that $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$ yet $P(A\cap B)=0$.

@r.e.s. Oh now I got it. My mistake was that I was assuming $(A_1 \cap A_2)$ not being null always implies $Pr(A_1 \cap A_2) > 0$. But now what if I change it to: if probability of any intersection events I.e $Pr(A_i \cap A_j) = 0 \quad \text{for all} \quad i \neq j$ then: $Pr(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Pr(A_i)$. if $Pr(A_i \cap A_j) > 0 \quad \text{for all} \quad i \neq j$ then: $Pr(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) < \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Pr(A_i)$. Is this correct now?

@AzharKhan No, that's not enough. You'd need to apply what's called the inclusion-exclusion principle, to take into account all the various intersections of multiple events.

@AzharKhan Also, you just said "not being null", when you must have meant "not being empty".  In the context of probabilities, as Konstruktor mentioned, "null set" refers to a set whose probability is zero. So the mistake has been in thinking that nonempty implies nonnull (or, equivalently, that null implies empty).

Your proof is not mathematically rigorous, as pointed out by Konstruktor. A correct proof using induction can be done as follows.
We use the following two facts:

if $X \subseteq Y$, then $\Pr(X) \le \Pr(Y)$.
if $X \cap Y = \emptyset$, then $\Pr(X \cup Y) = \Pr(X) + \Pr(Y)$ (follows from simple inclusion-exclusion).

The assertion holds for the base case $n=2$ because,
$\begin{align}
\Pr(A_1 \cup A_2) &= \Pr( \left( A_1 \setminus A_2 \right) \cup A_2 ) \qquad \text{because } A_1 \cup A_2 = \left( A_1 \setminus A_2 \right) \cup A_2 \\
&= \Pr(A_1 \setminus A_2) + \Pr( A_2 ) \qquad \text{by fact 2} \\
&\le \Pr(A_1) + \Pr( A_2 ) \qquad \text{by fact 1}.
\end{align}$
For the inductive step, assuming that the assertion holds for $n$, i.e., assuming that $\Pr(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Pr(A_i)$, for $n+1$ we have that
$\begin{align}
\Pr(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n \cup A_{n+1}) &\le \Pr(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) + \Pr(A_{n+1}) \qquad \text{by the case }n=2 \text{ with sets } A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n \text{ and } A_{n+1} \\
&\le \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Pr(A_i) \right) + \Pr(A_{n+1}) \qquad \text{ by inductive hypothesis} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \Pr(A_i)
\end{align}$
which completes the inductive step, and hence we are done. $\blacksquare$

For two sets $A_1, A_2$, we have
$$
Pr(A_1 \cup A_2) = Pr((A_1-A_1 \cap A_2) \cup (A_2 - A_1 \cap A_2) \cup (A_1 \cap A_2))
$$
$$
= Pr(A_1-A_1 \cap A_2) + Pr(A_2 - A_1 \cap A_2) + Pr(A_1 \cap A_2)
$$
$$
\leq Pr(A_1) + Pr(A_2) + Pr(A_1 \cap A_2)
$$
$$
\leq Pr(A_1) + Pr(A_2)
$$
I think you can continue the proof
